# Why upload image fails using Laravel 9 CRUD?

Tags: laravel, image, upload, crud

I am creating a database for books. When I was testing CRUD without image upload(normal CRUD), it was working. But when I added book cover image file as part of data input I get error "
**Argument #1 ($rules) must be of type array, Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in**
". I didn't understand what caused it, is it because validation or path image folder will be stored in?

**Here it is image of error.**
[image: Error Message]
[image: Error Continuation]

**Model/Buku.php**

```
class Buku extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'cover',
        'nama_buku',
        'author',
        'terbitan',
        'barcode',
        'ketersediaan',
    ];
}
```

I suspect the error is in controllers code but didn't know why normal CRUD succeed but image upload CRUD fails.

**Controllers/BukuController.php**

```
protected function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate($request, [
            'cover' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'nama_buku' => 'required',
        'author' => 'required',
        'terbitan' => 'required',
        'barcode' => 'required',
        'ketersediaan' => 'required',
        ]);
        $input = $request->all();
        if ($cover = $request->file('cover')) {
            $destinationPath = 'cover/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $cover->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $cover->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['cover'] = "$profileImage";
        }
        Buku::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('buku.index')->with('success','Buku has been created successfully.');
    }
```

I don't know if the errors is actually from input so just in case here is views create blade

**Views/create.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('buku.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Cover:</strong>
                        <input type="file" name="cover" placeholder="Cover Buku"
                        class="block w-full text-sm text-gray-500 file:mr-4 file:py-2 file:px-4 file:rounded-full file:border-0 file:text-sm file:font-semibold file:bg-blue-50 file:text-blue-700 hover:file:bg-blue-100" />
                        @error('cover')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Nama Buku:</strong>
                        <input type="text" name="nama_buku" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Buku">
                        @error('nama_buku')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Author:</strong>
                        <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" placeholder="Author Buku">
                        @error('author')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Terbitan:</strong>
                        <input type="text" name="terbitan" class="form-control" placeholder="Terbitan Buku">
                        @error('terbitan')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Barcode:</strong>
                        <input type="text" name="barcode" placeholder="Barcode Buku" id="scanner" />
                        @error('barcode')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Ketersediaan:</strong>
                        <input type="number" name="ketersediaan" class="form-control" placeholder="Ketersediaan Buku">
                        @error('ketersediaan')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-3">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I also tried image upload code when I was still using Laravel 4, still get the same error. Did anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states it pretty clearly. You pass a `Request` object where an array is expected.

Instead of using the object directly, you should use the `all()` method, which creates an array with all the posted fields in your request. Or in this case, you can leave the `request->all()` out, because the method is already called on the request object.

```
$request->validate($request,...)

$request->validate($request->all(),...)

$request->validate(['cover' => ....])
```

#########EDIT
It is also **not** recommended to insert all request data. You should only insert validated data.

```
$input = $request->all();
Buku::create($input);
```

You should use one of the two following approaches to only insert validated data: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#working-with-validated-input

Comment: Oh... that part. Thanks, I deleted the $request in validate and now it's working.

Comment: Also as a sidenote, when I tried adding $request->all() in validator, it gets BadMethodCallException error. So yeah, your explanation really help.

Comment: There is also the Validator facade which is called slightly different. In this case you would use it like this: `Validator::make($request->all(), [...])` this is where my initial thought came from